# Kernel of a homomorphism of modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra, $k$ a field. (Impose more conditions if you like.) For an element $f\in R$ consider the natural map
$\Omega^1_{R/k}\rightarrow\Omega^1_{R/(f)/k}$ which takes $dr$ to $d[r]$. This is obviously surjective. Is there an explicit description of the kernel? I can see that all $di$, $i\in I=(f)$ are in the kernel.

Comment: Clearly, all elements of the form $f\omega$ where $\omega\in \Omega^1_{R/k}$ are also in the kernel and these with $dx$, x\in fR$ as you noted generate the kernel.

Comment: @Mohan many thanks!